# Know which file is related to a process execution

Tags: unix, process, top

In Unix, with `top` I have an output similar to this:

```
13916 root 18 0 903m 129m 9936 S 51.4 0.1 3:07.01 php
```

How can I know which file is this php process executing?
For example:

```
13916 root 18 0 903m 129m 9936 S 51.4 0.1 3:07.01 php /var/www/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Hit `c` while running top. It will show the full command line, rather than just the process name.

Or to enable it from the command line you can run

> top -c

I don't have php installed to test, but here is an example from one of my systems

```
2378 root      20   0   19268   2104   1844 S   0.0  0.0   0:56.73 /usr/sbin/irqbalance --pid=/var/run/irqbalance.pid                                                                                    
 2461 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 [cfg80211]                                                                                                                            
 2468 root      20   0  917492  13412   8596 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.43 /usr/sbin/libvirtd                                                                                                                    
 2479 root      20   0    4248   1532   1384 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 /usr/sbin/acpid                                                                                                                       
 2513 root      20   0   71692   4884   4200 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 /usr/sbin/cups-browsed                                                                                                                
 2514 root      20   0  276012   4776   4012 S   0.0  0.0   0:18.67 /usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon                                                                                              
 2523 root      20   0  278500   4492   3816 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.06 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug                                                                                               
 2533 root      20   0   14408   1896   1752 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 /sbin/agetty --noclear tty1 linux                                                                                                     
 2593 root      20   0   24656   1772   1560 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 /usr/bin/kdm -config /var/run/kdm/kdmrc                                                                                               
 2621 root      20   0  262292  28976  11648 S   0.0  0.1   2:40.10 /usr/bin/X :0 vt7 -br -nolisten tcp -auth /var/run/xauth/A:0-4iKqJa                                                                   
 2627 ntp       20   0   37484   3896   3276 S   0.0  0.0   0:21.49 /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 115:126
```

Comment: `top -c` makes me see some more information (`20156 root  20   0  237m  55m 7852 R 71.4  0.3   0:01.64 /usr/bin/php`) but not the file executed.

Comment: @Mattia I've updated the answer. Is that what you are seeing with top -c?

Comment: Already tried, `top -c` show me more infos but not the file executed.